# post data to new tab via ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

Here is what I try to achieve: Let's say i have two files, order.php and print.php. In order.php there is a button for printing some data. When user clicks the button I want to post some data from order.php to print.php. Easy. But how?

This is my last attempt to do this.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '../event/print',
    async: false,
    data: {json:$("input[name=json]").val(),id:"2"},
    success:function(data){
        myWindow = window.open('../event/print', "_blank");
        myWindow.focus();
    },
    error:function(data){
        swal("Oops...", "Something went wrong.", "error");
    }
```

It shows me error alert everytime with 500 Internal Server Error.
What I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT**
I've changed some things around the web, and now it does not show any error. But I cant see any $_POST parameters.

Comment: I think the user also has togo to print? If so, why using ajax? In addition, you should check what's going wrong on the server. I assume it's your website, so debug if you are in development or check your log if you can't debug.

Comment: Are you just trying to add a new tab?  If so, you just need window.open http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp and pass the data as query parameters.  Your use of the word "file" here is confusing though, and doesn't make any sense on context.

Comment: 500 Internal Server Error means there s something wrong on server, some exception is occurring at server side.

Comment: I've changed some things around the web, and now it does not show any error. But I cant see any $_POST parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this way you are calling the page ../event/print twice.

The first time as a POST request via AJAX, the second time as a GET request due to the fact that you are opening a new tab.

What you are describing is not an AJAX request, it is just a form with target="_BLANK".

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_target.asp

```
<form action="../event/print" method="post" target="_blank">
...
```

Comment: Not exactly, but you're right. I am using the Nette framework, here is not easy set form action. So I used sessions. Thanx :)

Comment: Maybe assign an unique id to the "print" a use that during the get. It is more clean and more scalable.